# What's the overall list of Pokémon that can be faster than Trick Room?

Tags: pokemon-series, pokemon-eighth-generation

Basically, Trick Room is a move that inverses how speed works. However, through insanely complicated (and basically impossible in normal gameplay) setup, some Pokémon can have a speed stat that says "nuh-uh" and lets them move first during Trick Room. The prime example is Regieleki, *the* fastest Pokémon of all time.

But I wonder what other Pokémon can be faster than Trick Room's speed inversion?

(I know why this happens (stat overflow), but I want to know who can do it)

Comment: [This](https://www.reddit.com/r/stunfisk/comments/pd9h7t/comment/haq75qc/?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web3x&utm_name=web3xcss&utm_term=1&utm_content=share_button) Reddit thread contains a list of Pokemon that can do that, but I'm not sure if that's a complete list

Answer (score 14):

[Bulbapedia](https://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Trick_Room_(move)) states:

> From Generation V onwards, due to the way Trick Room affects Speed calculation, Pokémon with 1809 or more Speed will still act before Pokémon slower than 1809, even in Trick Room. Specifically, Pokémon with a Speed stat closest to 1809 without going under go first.

Thus, any Pokémon that can reach a speed of 1809 will be able to "outspeed" Trick Room. There are effects that can let you boost your speed - a Choice Scarf will give a 1.5 times speed boost, the move Tailwind will give a 2 times speed boost, and you can increase your speed by 6 stages to get a 4 times speed boost. In perfect conditions - level 100, holding a Choice Scarf, Tailwind in effect, +6 speed, 252 speed EVs, a speed boosting nature and 31 speed IVs, any Pokémon with a base speed of 20 or higher will reach a speed of at least 1824 and be able to "outspeed" the Trick Room. That means everything except for: Shuckle, Munchlax, Pyukumuku, Trapinch, Bonsly, Ferroseed, Gossifleur, Gimmighoul (chest form), Stakataka, Slowpoke, Galarian Slowpoke, Cleffa, Igglybuff, Wooper, Paldean Wooper, Pineco, Silcoon, Cascoon, Roggenrola, Foongus, Morelull, Sandygast and Pincurchin.

Furthermore, the move [Speed Swap](https://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Speed_Swap_(move)) allows a Pokémon to exchange its speed stat with another. So, if any Pokémon faster than base 20 speed (say, an Alakazam) uses Speed Swap on one of those listed Pokémon, they will also be able to "outspeed" Trick Room. Thus, the answer to the question is: every single Pokémon can be faster than Trick Room.

Comment: It's worth noting that Regieleki is so fast that in order for him to reach 402 speed at level 100 (with 3x speed and choice scarf, as close as possible to 1809) to achieve max speed under Trick Room, he actually needs a negative speed nature.

Comment: Wow, that is insane. Regieleki is really just that fast.